# Restored from Time Machine, no boot

Tags: time-machine, startup, performance

I restored from a Time Machine backup onto a new HDD, this was using a disc with OS X Lion

Upon boot, in verbose mode, the text hangs after `initpool: offset = 0x08000000 size = 0x0800000`.

I would be inclined to point to it being a RAM problem, but when another drive is hooked up, it goes on to list the partitions and then hangs. So it's most likely whatever sequence that happens right after the initpool function which is hanging

Why can't I get it to boot up? Also, I see something about the program Little Snitch starting, in case a third party program might be known to cause trouble.

Comment: Nevermind i am up and running, i didnt realize i needed to install lion after i restored from time machine

Answer (score 4):

A restore of Time Machine back to the drive will not restore it to a bootable state. You must install the OS onto the drive from the install download (Lion) or install disk (pre-Lion).

To do what you expected you need to make a *clone* of your boot drive. Use a tool like [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/). It makes an exact copy of your drive. If that drive happens to be your boot drive, then the clone is bootable.

**Time Machine is great for** recovering lost or earlier versions of your documents/data; **Carbon Copy Cloner is great for** keeping a current snapshot of your entire hard drive that is bootable. **Use Both**; I do.

Comment: Can you comment on Carbon Copy Cloner vs. SuperDuper! I use SD but have CCC. would love a technical discussion of both. Thanks.

Comment: What you say isn't so absolute. I booted lion installer does and then I click restore from Time Machine backup and you are right it was not bootable and I booted the lion install disk again and I click install lion and it didn't format the restored partition it just installed the lion system files and when it booted all of my time machine documents were in the right places everything my user profile is working

Comment: To clarify It did everything I expected without using DD cloner RSync SuperDrive or anything just Time Machine in line

Comment: Sorry @Richard, I have no experience with SuperDuper. I went with CCC because it's recommended on macperformanceguide.com